# How to get singleplayer universe up to speed when quests were advanced via multiplayer?

Tags: starbound

I can't be the first to be in this situation: I started my single player world and before I made any progress in the quests, I joined a friend's world and completed some of the quests there, unlocking the FTL drive and navigation and Ark stores.

Now, back in my own singleplayer universe, my ship's FTL drive is working and I can view navigation but can't actually go anywhere. I had to reactivate the Ark gateway on my planet in order to get there, but all the stores are boarded up as if I hadn't completed the quests. (The quest log is up to date with what I completed on my multiplayer world: the Floran scanner quest.)

Does anyone know how I can unlock the stores since I can't redo the quests?

Answer (score 2):

Okay I figured it outvia [a community post](https://community.playstarbound.com/threads/i-need-a-little-help-outpost-shops-reset.119365/).

This may be helpful to total beginners. You can enable admin mode by pressing `Enter` to open the chat window and then typing `/admin`. Then to set the shops back you use command `/setuniverseflag outpost_mission1` (basically this tells the world that you've finished the scanner quest which unlocks the shops). The link has several other admin commands to fix the world up.